# What rules govern robotic teleoperations, when the remote device also transmits back telemetric information?

Tags: united-states, legal, telecommand, telemetry

I was looking through the FCC part 97 rules for robotic teleoperation, and it cites a one-watt figure for "model craft". However, it also allows higher power transmissions for remotely operated stations, and beacons.

The robot in question is a land vehicle that traverses very hilly/mountainous terrain, and having a higher power communications link would be very handy. Additionally, it sends back video and instrument readings from it's surroundings.

What rules govern such devices? I was unable to find such regulations.

Comment: So....it's Pathfinder?

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Are you referring to the Nissan Vehicle? No, it's not for that. It's for a student engineering team for building robots.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the Mars rover.

Comment: @Tyzoid you really don't have to use amateur bands for that – depending on local legislation, it doesn't seem that hard to get a temporary license for telemetry/control, especially when using tested modules.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Kind of, see http://urc.marssociety.org/

Comment: @MarcusMüller Not quite sure, we'd have to check. We have several hams on the team anyway, so we'd be looking to use that ability if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[§97.215](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=336ab7469b61ecbfa15086dbf1bf2c59&rgn=div5&view=text&node=47:5.0.1.1.6&idno=47#se47.5.97_1215) has rules for "model craft". It says a station *may* be operated under those rules. To me, the intent of those rules is to allow for control of RC models without a break to identify every 10 minutes. I'd guess for a rover designed for Mars, a brief identification break is not a problem.

However, the rover is a station, and there won't be anyone at it. I'd think [§97.213 Telecommand of an amateur station](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=336ab7469b61ecbfa15086dbf1bf2c59&rgn=div5&view=text&node=47:5.0.1.1.6&idno=47#se47.5.97_1213) would allow operation in that case:

> An amateur station on or within 50 km of the Earth's surface may be under telecommand where:
>
> (a) There is a radio or wireline control link between the control point and the station sufficient for the control operator to perform his/her duties. If radio, the control link must use an auxiliary station. A control link using a fiber optic cable or another telecommunication service is considered wireline.
>
> (b) Provisions are incorporated to limit transmission by the station to a period of no more than 3 minutes in the event of malfunction in the control link.
>
> (c) The station is protected against making, willfully or negligently, unauthorized transmissions.
>
> (d) A photocopy of the station license and a label with the name, address, and telephone number of the station licensee and at least one designated control operator is posted in a conspicuous place at the station location.

So the salient points seem to be:

1. Tape a license and contact information on the rover
2. Put a 3-minute transmit timeout on the rover
3. The controlling station must be an [auxiliary station](http://www.arrl.org/auxiliary-station-faq) (which, among other things, limits you to VHF and higher frequencies)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the information I'd need. If I recall correctly, this applies even down to the 10m band? Or would I need to stay 2m and smaller?

Comment: @Tyzoid 2m and smaller. See [§97.201(b)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=336ab7469b61ecbfa15086dbf1bf2c59&rgn=div5&view=text&node=47:5.0.1.1.6&idno=47#se47.5.97_1201)